# Can not parse the data from yaml file

Tags: java, yaml, testng-dataprovider

I want to use dataprovider with yaml files.I created yaml files, DataWrapper class, Pojo classes, YamlProvider class.I got reader exception and
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList&lt;provider.SubmissionPj&gt;` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (BufferedInputStream); line: 3, column: 7]

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hello, please post the failing `yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem without using any additional class. I create my own parser which is return list of HashMap<String,String>